# Why is there a noise and big flame when starting my gas cooker?

Tags: stove, gas

I installed a new gas bottle a few days ago for my stove and trying to find out why the following is happening.

When the gas hasn't been used for a few hours, the moment you turn the gas button on the stove there is what looks like a higher pressure wave that comes with a large flame and a 'wooof' sound when the gas ignites.

The the stove works normally. It takes 3-4 hours of not using it for this to occur again.

It looks like there is a pressure buildup in the gas line when it's not in use.

What could be the reason?

---

Here is a video: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gN1fJ.jpg

If you want sound for a full experience: https://we.tl/p9CR4Dihok :)

Comment: You might want to post a picture or two, especially of all connections

Comment: I've edited the post with a video.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like delayed ignition where a greater than normal amount of gas is present when the burner gets spark.  If you manually initiate the spark independent of turning on the gas you might try starting the spark first and then turning on the gas.  Also the spark ignitor may be slightly out of place, moved during cleaning, etc.  There are all sorts of stoves.  A photo of the controls, burner and ignitor would help.  You could also check the manual.

After viewing/hearing the video it seems to me the ignition is rather forceful.  This might point to the regulator and too high gas pressure.  A technician could test the gas pressure after the regulator.

Comment: In the video, the tic-tic-tic sound you can hear is the igniter, it is started several seconds ahead of the gas, so there is spark by the time the gas arrives.

Answer (score 0):

I assume with bottled gas that the regulator is on/near the cylinder rather than built in to the stove. All bottled gas systems I've used are like this.  If so you should try replacing the regulator.  They're not expensive and they don't last forever. They can also get particles in them when changing cylinders, that degrade their performance.At the same time you should check the hoses are in good condition (some regulators and hoses come as sets, but I've no idea what system you've got).  Is the flame noticeably bigger than before?  That would be further evidence of a bad regulator.

Another less likely thought: Does it light as quickly as normal when it does this, or does it take a little longer? A mix of gas and air in the line can cause this (it does in my camper van).  I say less likely because of your "as soon as".

You mention that it starts sparking well before it ignites (I couldn't load the video with sound when you posted it).  I've had this with my stove when the gas distributor crown is partly blocked , so gas doesn't flow towards the ignitor directly.  On mine there's an enameled cast iron cap that lifts off, revealing the nozzle, mixing chamber, and crown.  Make sure all of that is clean and dry.  This is most likely when it's just one burner that's at fault.

Comment: I've added a video to demonstrate.

Comment: I still think some details of the regulator would be a good idea

Comment: I'll take a photo and post here

Answer (score 0):

Can you reduce how much the valve on the bottle is open by ? I use LPG and get a similar although not as dramatic effect.